# Sphinx multiple dynamic databases index

Tags: php, mysql, database, sphinx

In my situation, I have one web app with multiple databases; one DB per registered client. As these databases are created on user registration, I cannot manually add as these sources to sphinx config. But all databases has the same strucure and search queries are the same; just different database names and data of course. So, the question is; 
Can sphinx be configured to fetch database list from e.g. ini or other external file and then make index for these databases? Then, can I pass database name in query to fetch results from specified db index?
Or there are other tools, other approaches for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trick with a *sphinx.conf* file. If it is executable, Sphinx tries to execute it and accepts its output as the configuration. For example, you can merge several config file into a single one:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sphinx configuration
cat /usr/local/etc/sphinx.d/*.conf
```

You can use this trick to build a config which indexes all your databases.